# How to use Flink 1.9 LAST_VALUE?

Tags: sql, apache-flink, olap

I am trying to use Flink's 1.9 LAST_VALUE. Unlike the Alibaba docs, it does not accept a second argument for ORDER and it does not like the OVER(...) clause. So, I am not sure, how to feed into LAST_VALUE a criteria?

I was hoping that if you set the processing to "event-time", last_value would return the latest value based on event-time, but instead, it is returning the latest value read?

Answer (score 0):

The function `LAST_VALUE` is only supported by the Blink planner when running SQL on Flink. One needs to explicitly activate the usage of the Blink planner via

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.EnvironmentSettings;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.java.StreamTableEnvironment;

StreamExecutionEnvironment bsEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
EnvironmentSettings bsSettings = EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().useBlinkPlanner().inStreamingMode().build();
StreamTableEnvironment bsTableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(bsEnv, bsSettings);
```

Only then, you should be able to run SQL queries containing the `LAST_VALUE` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already know it, if you read the above closer, I am complaining that it does not accept an OVER clause or a second ORDER input argument according to the blink commercial version? So, how one should feed the criteria for LAST_VALUE, LAST_VALUE based on what?